# Fixing the position of a polygon

Tags: html, css, svg, css-position, polygon

I've been trying for a while now to make this SVG to work, but to no avail. What I'm trying is to make the triangle not move itself whenever I modify the size of the window.

```css
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

html,body{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}

#nose{
    stroke: black;
    stroke-width: 2px;
    fill: #ffd9b3;
    position: fixed;
}
.svg{
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="svg">
    <svg width="400px" height="500px">
        <ellipse id="face" cx="15vw" cy="15vw" rx="10vw" ry="12vw"></ellipse>
        <polygon id="nose" points="170,210 210,210 190,130"></polygon>
    </svg>
</div>
</body>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Why do you need to use `vw`?

Comment: I'm trying to make it responsive, so I thought that would work

Comment: It'not responsive. The svg element has a size in px! In order to make it responsive you may use a viewBpx attribute instead of the width and height: `viewBox = "0 0 400 500"`. Next you use user units (no units) for the ellipse

Comment: alright. I will try that. thanks for the advice!